# few methods missing in WriteableBitmapEx

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, writeablebitmapex

As i see the codeplex site for WriteableBitmapEx :-

http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

I can see methods like flip,rotate etc. But when i download the assembly, add reference and check for these methods they are not available. Can anybody tell me what am i missing?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem when I downloaded the compiled version (I think it was WriteableBitmapEx_v0.9.5.0).  I just downloaded the latest source, available [here](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets), and compiled the library.  All of the methods you're missing are present.

Comment: Yep, I really need to build a new version. :) Expect something in 1 or 2 weeks.